# Get the values of a specific div vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to get the values ​​of this div shown in the link that I propose. 
Is there some kind soul who could show me the solution? I'm not here to ask for the code, but are diffcult and would like some help.

I'm trying to use the WebBrowser control, but so far nothing.

```
 Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    Dim result
    For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
        If d.GetAttribute("className") = "block_competition_tables real-content clearfix " Then
            result = d.InnerText
        End If
        MsgBox(result)
    Next
```

Image example:

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/e9de/4ju6fo9cp6ibl84fg.jpg

Site link:

http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20142015/regular-season/r27139/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because your using className as the attribute name, when it should be class.

Have you tried getting the div by id

> page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8_block_competition_form_table_1

instead, it wont break if they change the css that way (although it may still break if they change the layout but you will probably have other issues to fix then anyway).

EDIT:

Ahh figured it out, not only does that page not seem to work well in a web browser control (lots of javascript errors on my windows 8 box) the table is loaded dynamically when you click the link so its not there when you try get it.

If you look at the network tab of developer tools in chrome (or in whatever browser you use) it'll show a GET request to

`http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_tables?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8&callback_params=%7B%22season_id%22%3A9757%2C%22round_id%22%3A27139%2C%22outgroup%22%3Afalse%7D&action=changeTable&params=%7B%22type%22%3A%22competition_form_table%22%7D`

which if you decode the URL params is

`http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_tables?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8&callback_params={"season_id":9757,"round_id":27139,"outgroup":false}&action=changeTable&params={"type":"competition_form_table"}`

going to the url gave me the html of the table in a json object, and you can do that with a simple HTTPRequest instead of using a webbrowser.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nope, the msgbox contents is empty :\